Continuing the hexadecimal sequence 9bf66a6a87, 9bfd91c857, 9c0501e2ae, 9c0991af27, 9c0d27e6ec,

Given the following sequence of hexadecimals, figure out how to generate the next few in the sequence:
9bf66a6a87
9bfd91c857
9c0501e2ae
9c0991af27
9c0d27e6ec


My approach
I noticed that, by transforming the numbers into decimal form, you get the following
669854100103
669974120535
670098907822
670175440679
670235617004

Looking at the 4 starting digits, you can cleary see a pattern emerging.
$$ 6698 => 6699 => 6700 => 6701 => 6702 $$
I tried using the first 4 digits to figure out the next 8 but I'm stuck.
I also tried splitting the numbers into 3 groups of 4 digits, and trying to figure out a way to transform any 4 digits into the next 4, but also to no avail
6698 => 5410
5410 => 0103
6699 => 7412
7412 => 0535
6700 => 9890
9890 => 7822
6701 => 7544 
7544 => 0679
6702 => 3561 
3561 => 7004

Any suggestions?

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

(Closed pending suitable attribution. Once that's provided, the question can be opened again.)

Knowing where the question came from isn't just a matter of providing credit where due, avoiding suspicions of plagiarism, etc. (though those things do matter). It can also be very helpful in solving a puzzle -- there may be context that suggests what sort of thing to look at.
